# unable to access VertX evo V1000 and V100 gateway

Tags: javascript, hid, common-access-card

I'm trying to access VertX EVO V1000 and V100 Gateway for access controlling using JAVASCRIPT but unable to do so.

Please help me out. I'm open to try any kind of solutions to do so but only using JavaScript.

I've trying using modbus-serial npm module but only able to connect with the controller IP Address but unable to do any further proceeding.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to build a module for access control system using VertX EVO V1000 and V100 but unable to access them using JAVASCRIPT(NodeJS). Need help for getting information about those hardware module that how can I access them. As I know the IP of that device but unable to access them through the code. Need to know how can I access those devices through the code using which npm module as I'm unable to get information about that. How can I read my smart card using the smart card reader(s) attached with the EVO V100 which is connected to EVO V1000 controller.